# PHP get value from url and pass it to text field

Tags: php

Hi I am a jsf programmer and want to integrate a documents repositary developed using php in my jsf application. So what i am doing is when the user clicks a link from my jsf screen it gets a value for the link pass it to the php url and opens a page where the user can add docs.
I am getting the value from url and displaying it in the page. But what i want is instead of user entering the *number field(please look at the screen shot)  the value from URL should pass automatically to the database as number and the number field should be removed . Please look at screen shots.

[image]
[image]

and the code snippets

```
<td class="ThRows">*Number</td>
$cellvalue = "";
if ((!isset($_GET["add_fd9"])) && (!isset($_POST["add_fd9"]))) {
$itemvalue = "";
} else {
$itemvalue = qsrequest($_GET["add_fd9");
```

then

fieldPrompts[_No] = "*Number";

pgitm_No= document.getElementsByName("add_fd9")[0];

I dont understand where to pass the url value

Comment: can't see screenshot and use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET/$POST`...

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
$cellvalue = "";
if (!isset($_REQUEST["add_fd9"])) {
$itemvalue = "";
} else {
$itemvalue = qsrequest($_REQUEST["add_fd9"]);
}
```

Comment: '$$cellvalue = "";
if (!isset($_REQUEST["add_fd9"])) {
$itemvalue = "";
} else {
$itemvalue = qsrequest($_REQUEST["id"]);
}'
Instead of add_f9 i want to pass value from url which i am getting in id. Is it correct

Comment: yes i did that. no change..same value which user enters is getting saved. is that because php changes take time to take place or something

Answer (score 0):

Use 
    $_REQUEST

as

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value="<?php echo isset($_REQUEST['add_fd9'])?$_REQUEST['add_fd9']:'';?>">
```